# I am trying to use NumPy for a python 3.10 project

Tags: windows, python-3.10

when i use the code `import numpy as np` i get the return of
`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>      import numpy  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`
I have confirmed that the files for numpy do exist in the package directory
Numpy version 1.25.0